# How to simulate on href with ref

Tags: javascript, iphone, element, html-lists

I try to simulate a JS click on UIWebView (i can do this by document.getElementById('MyId'));

But in this exemple, we found a REF element, how to get it to click?

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="details" ref="1" title="|title" class="detail_button tips">
```

Comment: +1 because I like your gravitar

Comment: Please give more detail, preferably with a code sample.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="details" ref="1" title="title" class="detail_button tipsStandard slideIn">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('MyId').onclick=function(){
    var ref = this.getAttribute('ref');
    //the ref is your value
    if(ref == 1){
        this.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the ref value attribute like this

```
document.getElementById('MyId').getAttribute('ref');
```

Comment: this return the value 1. But how to: document.getElementById('details').getAttribute('ref').REF_I_WANT_SELECT.click();

Answer (score 0):

Say you have these links

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="MyId"  title="title" >1</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="MyId" ref="1" title="title" >1</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="MyId1" ref="1" title="title" >2</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="MyId2" ref="1" title="title" >3</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="MyId3" ref="1" title="title" >4</a>
```

and you whant only the ones that have the ref attribute set to some value to add a click event? well if this is the case this code will do this for you.

```
aElements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");          
       for (i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
           if (aElements[i].hasAttribute("ref") && aElements[i].hasAttribute("ref") == 1) {

               aElements[i].onclick = function () {
                   alert(2);                    
               }
           }
       }
```